# 実行内容に改行を含む場合のリスト内包表記の書き方について

Tags: python

以下のようなコードをリスト内包表記に直したいです

```
mylist = [1,2,3,4]

for i in mylist:
    print(i)
    print(i%2)
```

以下のように書いて試してみましたがエラーになりました。

```
mylist = [1,2,3,4]

[print(i);print(i%2); for i in mylist]
```

エラー内容は以下の通りです。

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

どうやったら改行を含む処理をリスト内包表記で表現できますか？
関数を1つ作るしかないですか？

Comment: `[print(i, i%2, sep='\n') for i in mylist]` や `[print(f'{i}\n{i%2}') for i in mylist]` の様な書き方もできます。

Comment: tuple の話が出ているので、参考までに `[print(i) or print(i%2) for i in mylist]` という書き方もあります。ただ、この様な書き方は避けて、関数化するか for 文を使うことをお勧めします(文(statement)が使えますので)。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

基本的には、akira ejiriさんの回答のオマケのようなものなのですが、

> ## リスト内包表記の文法
>
> [式 for 制御変数 in イテラブルなオブジェクト]

要は、`for`の前に式が来れば良いので、tupleを使うこともできそうです。

```
[(print(i),print(i%2)) for i in mylist]
```

無理に1つの`print`関数の呼び出しに変換する必要がなく、`print`以外の式を順番に実行したい場合にも使えるのでより簡単かと。

---

ちなみに上記を評価した結果の値は以下のようなものになります。

> `[(None, None), (None, None), (None, None), (None, None)]`

結果のリストが要らないのにリスト内包表記を使った方が良いかどうか、意見が別れそうに思うのですが、Python公式から何らかのガイドラインが出ているかは見つけられませんでした。

Comment: ちなみにpython2系だと、`print`は1つだけでも「文」なんで、リスト内包表記には使えないですね。

Answer (score 2):

## 回答

リスト内包表記で質問された方のコードを書き直してみました。

```
mylist2 = [(i,i%2) for i in mylist]
for i, i2 in mylist2:
    print(i)
    print(i2)
```

## 質問された方のコードがエラーとなった理由

`print(i);print(i%2);`が式ではなく、文であるためにエラーとなりました。

**追記**
 質問にコメントされた方の方法を実行してみました。こちらの方がシンプルですね。

```
[print(i, i%2, sep='\n') for i in mylist]
[print(f'{i}\n{i%2}') for i in mylist]
```

`print(i);print(i%2);`は文ですが、`print(i)`や`print(i%2)`は式なのですね。思ってもみませんでした。

## リスト内包表記の文法

[式 for 制御変数 in イテラブルなオブジェクト]

## その他

> 実行内容に改行を含む場合のリスト内包表記の書き方について

質問のタイトルにある`改行`はリスト内包表記とは関係ないと思います。

↑
**以上は見当外れな記述でした。リスト内包表記に実行処理が書けるとは知りませんでした。**